# Compiler Error Message in row LinkButton declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I have the following ASP code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="edit item" onclick='AddItem.aspx?catid=<%# Eval("CollectionID")%>' />
```

In this row i get Error compilation:

Compiler Error Message: CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line

Why do I get this error and how can i fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="edit item" 
PostBackUrl='AddItem.aspx?catid=<%# Eval("CollectionID")%>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that *this* is the line causing the problem? Generally when you see this error it is because there is a problem with your <@ > page directives at the top of the code. Make sure your <@Page> directive is the very first thing in the file and that it's formatted correctly and that you don't have any other <@ symbols in your code aside from your page directives.

Comment: Yes,I get this line in red at compilation.